# Calling server code from client folder

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I have a template in my client folder that reads a file that a user uploads:

```
Template.upload.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        var file1 = document.getElementById("file1").files;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var contents = event.target.result;

            /** This code needs to run in server folder **/
            var nodeFS = Meteor.npmRequire('node-fs');
            var fs = new nodeFS({version:'0.1.7'});
        };

        reader.readAsText(file1[0]);
    }
});
```

What's the best Meteor practice for handling situations like this? I'm assuming that I have to create a file in the server folder that has a function that will take my file as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want client code to run on the server you should use [Meteor Methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/methods).

But, using meteor to store files has always been a bit tricky. Because of this there are a lot of file packages available if you search on atmosphere. My favorite is to use [lepozepo](https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3) because it will upload your stuff to an S3 bucket for you and is in general really easy to use.

If you don't want to use S3 (can't imagine why) the you can use something like [cfs:filesystem](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/filesystem) to accomplish what you're trying to do.

I hope this helps.